# Waterline Error implementation in sails.js Services

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

As most of you know sails.js framework throws error as WLError object, I would like to make this consistent across my application. Any I error I would like to raise in my services should be a WLError object with my own error,status & summary. Has anyone done this?

```
var error = new Error(errorMsg);
return error;
```

I want something like below...

```
var error = new WLError({"status":"Fail", "error": "somethig", "summary": "OOPS!!"}); 
return error;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this...

I added below in bootstrap.js

```
sails.WLError = require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLError.js');
```

Then in my code need not do a "require". Just below lines works.

```
error = new sails.WLError();
error.code = "404";
error.status = "Failure";
error.summary = "Invalid Request";
error.details = errorMsg;
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my adapters I use waterline errors

```
    // Adjust the relative path as needed
    var WLError = require('../../sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLError');

    processError: function(error) {
      var formattedErr = new WLError();
      formattedErr.code = 'E_MY_ERROR';
      formattedErr.status = 400;
      formattedErr.reason = error;
      formattedErr.details = error;
      return formattedErr;
    },
```

Also I did just the opposite, converting waterline errors to look like other sails errors

in api/responses/badRequest.js I added:

```
      // If the user-agent wants JSON, always respond with JSON
      if (req.wantsJSON) {
        try {
          // This formats waterline errors like other sails errors
          // See WLError.prototype.toJSON in waterline/error/WLError.js
          var WLResponse = data.toJSON();
          if(WLResponse.hasOwnProperty('error') && WLResponse.hasOwnProperty('summary')) {
            return res.jsonx({
              code: WLResponse.error,
              message: WLResponse.summary
            });
          } else {
            // Not a waterline error
            throw 'NonWLError';
          }
        } catch (e) {
          return res.jsonx(data);
        }
      }
```